# Dynamic DropDown in excel

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dropdown list of states,districts,sub-districts etc. By selecting one of the states from drpoDown list of states, District dropdown should contain only list of districts which are belonging that particular state. How can do that using vba code. Is it really possible??

Comment: Is it really necessary to use VBA? This can be done without VBA.

Comment: One video worth a thousand words : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-78bH0RZ7MA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit rough idea... try it - I have designed all in **sheet2**
First create Data

```
[A1]    [B1]    [C1]
State   Dist    SubDist
State1  Dist1   SD1
State1  Dist1   SD1
State1  Dist1   SD1
State1  Dist1   SD2
State1  Dist1   SD2
State1  Dist2   SD1
State1  Dist2   SD1
State1  Dist2   SD2
State1  Dist2   SD2
State1  Dist2   SD2
State1  Dist3   SD3
State1  Dist3   SD3
State2  Dist1   SD1
State2  Dist1   SD1
State2  Dist1   SD1
State2  Dist1   SD2
State2  Dist1   SD2
State2  Dist2   SD1
State2  Dist2   SD1
State2  Dist2   SD2
State2  Dist2   SD2
State2  Dist2   SD2
State2  Dist3   SD3
State2  Dist3   SD3
```

Crete Criteria for Advance Filter
    [J1]    [K1]    [L1]
    State   Dist    SubDist
    State1  Dist1

First Add the Unique State Value in Dropdown 1 'drpState' and assign getDist() to the Dropdown for State Selection (make 2 more for other selecitons like dist, sub dist...)

Create 3 Dropdowns 'drpState'[Macro: getDist()], 'drpDist'[Macro: getSDist()], 'drpSDist'

```
Sub getDist()'<< Assign to State Selection
    Call GetDropdownValue("drpState", Sheet2.Range("J2"))
    Sheet2.Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 1).Clear
    Call GetSubList("drpDist", 2, Sheet2.Range("O1"))
End Sub

Sub getSDist() '<< Assign to Destic Selection
    Call GetDropdownValue("drpDist", Sheet2.Range("K2"))
    Call GetSubList("drpSDist", 3, Sheet2.Range("O1"))
End Sub

Sub GetDropdownValue(ByVal DropdownName As String, OutPutRange As Range)
    With Sheet2.DropDowns(DropdownName)
        OutPutRange.Value = .List(.ListIndex)
    End With
End Sub

Sub GetSubList(ByVal DropdownName As String, ByVal intLevel As Integer, ByVal OutPutRange As Range)

    Dim rngMainData As Range
    Dim rngList     As Range

    If OutPutRange.Value <> vbNullString Then
        OutPutRange.CurrentRegion.Clear
    End If

    Set rngMainData = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Resize(, intLevel)
    rngMainData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, Sheet2.Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Resize(, intLevel), OutPutRange, True

    With OutPutRange.CurrentRegion.Columns(intLevel)
        Set rngList = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With

    With Sheet2.DropDowns(DropdownName)
        .List = rngList.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I think this will help you resolve your query...

Comment: Create Dropdowns using FormControls 'drpDist', 'drpDist'

Comment: O1 is the place where filtered data will appear
and K1 if the selected data from the dropdown
     [J]              [K]         [L]
1   **State        Dist     SubDist**
2   State2        Dist1

Comment: As you can see in image i have shared, There are 4 different things you needs to create: (1) 3 Dropdowns (2) Data (3) Filter Criteria and last one Range for the Output

Comment: how to create filter criteria and output range??

Comment: I have created the data and dropdowns. I have created dropdown using form controls only also i have assigned  cell link for each dropdown as G1,G2,G3

Comment: As you can see in image there are 3 headings [State], [Dist], [SubDist] in both Data and FilterCriteria and Output Too. now you have to put the value for each of the headings as you selected by using dropdowns (chk  **GetDropdownValue** in code)| As you have already done the advance filter.

Comment: if you assign cell link to the dropdown it will return index no, we dont need that we need the selected value form the dropdown. 
gime ur email id ill give you a sample...

Comment: The data which User selected I want to send it to database I think this code will increase redundancy. Can you give idea how to make it efficient also/

Comment: rajanirampelli@gmail.com

Comment: This code is just to Create ur dropdown list at many sublevels

Answer (score 1):

Say we have the primary drop-down in cell **B2** based on the values in column **H**:

[image]

Column **I** contains the secondary drop-down info as **comma separated lists,** each list in a single cell.  The following event macro will detect changes to cell **B2** and establish the DV in cell **C2** accordingly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim v As Variant, r As Range
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Range("B2").Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    v = Target.Value
    Set r = Range("H3:H5").Find(What:=v, After:=Range("H3")).Offset(0, 1)
    v = r.Value

    With Range("C2").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=v
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here is how the **C2** pull-down will appear:

[image]

Comment: Nicely done answer. However, won't it just put the whole cell value into the new DV : "beagle, pug, collie" ? I think what OP meant, was that based on one selection from list in B2, another DV **list** in C2 will appear. On each separate line : "beagle" *next line* "pug" *next line* "collie".

Comment: @BranislavKollár  Give it a try............... *DV* can be setup with either a partial column of cells or a **comma-separated string.**

Comment: Its working but this will work for only 2 dropdown list. But i want the code for 4 dropdown list

Comment: State is selected district dropdown should fill with all corresponding districts.And if district is selected subdistrict DropDown should be fill with corresponding sub districts similarly for the 4th dropdown...